# ggplot: how to add common x and y labels to a grid of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `diamonds`, I want to plot `carat` vs `price` for 4 levels (`Fair`, `Good`, `Very Good` and `Premimum`) of `cut`.

Instead of allowing `facet_wrap()`to control the breaks in the axes, I made four plots to control the breaks in axes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)
library(grid)
f1 <- 
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$cut=="Fair",], aes(carat, price))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol =2)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,4), breaks=c(0,  1, 2, 3, 4))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10000), breaks=c(0,  2500, 5000, 7500, 10000))+
  labs(x=expression(" "),
       y=expression(" "))


f2 <- 
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$cut=="Good",], aes(carat, price))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol =2)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,5000), breaks=c(0,  1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000))+
  labs(x=expression(" "),
       y=expression(" "))


f3 <- 
  ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$cut=="Very Good",], aes(carat, price))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol =2)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1), breaks=c(0, 0.2,  0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000), breaks=c(0,  200, 400, 600, 800, 1000))+
  labs(x=expression(" "),
       y=expression(" "))

f4 <- 
  ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$cut=="Premium",], aes(carat, price))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol =2)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1.5), breaks=c(0, 0.2,  0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3000), breaks=c(0,  500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000))+
  labs(x=expression(" "),
       y=expression(" "))

fin_fig <- ggarrange(f1, f2, f3, f4, ncol =2)
fin_fig
```

**RESULT**

*Each plot has a range of different y values*

[image]

**QUESTION**

In all facets, x and y axes are the same. The only difference is the min, max and the breaks. I want to add x and y labels to this figure. I can do this manually in any word document or image editor. Is there anyway to do it in R directly?

Comment: have a look at `grid::textGrob` and `ggplot2::annotation_custom`

Comment: you could use `gridExtra`, which has the `left` and `bottom` arguments. : `p <- ggplot() ; g <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p,p,p,p,ncol=2,  bottom=grid::textGrob("bottom lab"), left=grid::textGrob("left lab", rot=90)) ; grid::grid.newpage() ; grid::grid.draw(g)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to using functions from the `gridExtra` package (as suggested by @user20650), you can also create your plots with less code by splitting the `diamonds` data frame by levels of `cut` and using `mapply`.

The answer below also includes solutions for follow-up questions in the comments. We show how to lay out the four plots, add single x and y labels (including making them bold and controlling their color and size) that apply to all the plots, and get a single legend rather than a separate legend for each plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(scales)
```

Remove rows where `cut` is `"Ideal"`:

```
dat = diamonds[diamonds$cut != "Ideal",]
dat$cut = droplevels(dat$cut)
```

Create four plots, one for each remaining level of `cut` and store in a list. We use `mapply` (instead of `lapply`) so that we can provide both separate data frames for each level of `cut` and a vector of custom `ymax` values to set the highest value on the y-axis separately for each plot. We also add `color=clarity` in order to create a color legend:

```
pl = mapply(FUN = function(df, ymax) {
  ggplot(df, aes(carat, price, color=clarity))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~cut, ncol=2)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,4), breaks=0:4)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, ymax), labels=dollar_format()) +
    labs(x=expression(" "),
         y=expression(" "))
}, df=split(dat, dat$cut), ymax=c(1e4,5e3,1e3,3e3), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Okay, we have our four plots, but each one has its own legend. So now we want to arrange to have only one overall legend. We do this by extracting one of the legends as a separate grob (**gr**aphical **ob**ject) and then removing the legends from the four plots.

Extract the legend as a separate grob using a small helper function:

```
# Function to extract legend
# https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend) }

# Extract legend as a grob
leg = g_legend(pl[[1]])
```

Now we need to arrange the four plots in a 2x2 grid and then place the legend to the right of this grid. We use `arrangeGrob` to lay out the plots (and note how we use `lapply` to remove the legend from each plot before rendering it). This is essentially the same as what we did with `grid.arrange` in an earlier version of this answer, except that `arrangeGrob` creates the 2x2 plot grid object without drawing it. Then we lay out the legend beside the 2x2 plot grid by wrapping the whole thing inside `grid.arrange`. `widths=c(9,1)` allocates 90% of the horizontal space to the 2x2 grid of plots and 10% to the legend. Whew!

```
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(grobs=lapply(pl, function(p) p + guides(colour=FALSE)), ncol=2, 
              bottom=textGrob("Carat", gp=gpar(fontface="bold", col="red", fontsize=15)), 
              left=textGrob("Price", gp=gpar(fontface="bold", col="blue", fontsize=15), rot=90)),
  leg, 
  widths=c(9,1)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Please, check the update to see the reason I couldn't use "less code". I had to make four different plots because all have different range of y and x values but still they have the same unit.

Comment: See update. I've changed to `mapply` so that we can include an argument to set the top of the y-axis separately for each plot.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.
Any suggestions how to change the size and the face (to be bold) of the labels?

Comment: See updated code. I threw in color and font size as well, in case that's of interest.

Comment: Another question if you please, what if color the points based on the variable color. Is it possible to have only one legend for the four plots?

Comment: See updated code. I added a color aesthetic to get a legend and the I show how to lay out the plots with a single legend.

Comment: Thanks :-) I have just posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011020/ggplot-align-plots-together-and-add-common-labels-and-legend about legend and aligning the two plots.

Comment: I wish there is a way I can upvote your answer more than one time. I really appreciate your time and help.